# How to create a squeezed box using only css

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am thinking how to style a squizzed box like this:

[image]

I found that I can achieve a similar result with pseudo elements and border-radius as percentage.
Here is the CodePen: https://codepen.io/micu22/pen/eYzpmqR
And here is the code:

```
div {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
div::after,
div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
}
div::before {
  top: -17px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div::after {
  bottom: -17px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

But maybe there is an easier or just more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like below, using gradient coloration and an SVG filter:

```css
.box {
   width:200px;
   height:250px;
   background:
     /*                   v-- adjust the 15% here */
     radial-gradient(50% 15% at top,   transparent 98.5%,lightblue) top,
     radial-gradient(50% 15% at bottom,transparent 98.5%,lightblue) bottom;
   background-size:100% 51%;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   filter: url('#goo');
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>                                  <!-- adjust the the 13 here --v         -->
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="13" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks I am using an svg icon set for my project so this will be easy to add. I have never worked with svg filters and this looks interesting! What do you think of the answer @mfast gave?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the content is going to exist. If this is a fixed height container, I'd probably opt for a solution using an SVG background.

I think the most elegant (or at least intrinsic) solution would involve using [clipping paths.](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) This would allow you to create an SVG of the exact shape you want and clip the container or background image for the container so that you aren't disguising a still technically visible part of the element.

[Clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) is a great tool if you've never worked with clipping masks before.