# Create curved background with box-shadow

Tags: html, css

I tried to create this curve background with html and css but I got problem with adding box-Shadow to the div
[image]

so I create it with a **div** and **before** / **after**

and the result is that:

```css
.background::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background: #fff;
}
.background{
  position: relative;
  background: #0b2864;
  width:100%;
  height:30rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}
.background::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-2.2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
</div>
```

BTW my question is different than this question
[How to create a squeezed box using only css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64325025/how-to-create-a-squeezed-box-using-only-css)
I want to add box-shadow to my div not just create it
and I need it to be **html css** not **svg**.
for responsivity

Comment: what about svg? btw the bottom ellipse must be above the rectangle, but should be under the shadow, its impossible

Comment: in the duplicate, update the filter value with `url('#goo') drop-shadow(0 0 6px black)` to add the shadow

Comment: @palmarbg no svg are not useful in this part I need use css only